# foreach array returning non-order specific values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get 'name' of 'shipping_option's relating to a specific order.

```
            $shipping_options = $order->get_items( 'shipping_option' );
        
        foreach ( $shipping_options as $item_id => $item  ) {
            $delivery_date_time[] = $item['name'];
        }
        $this->xml_append( $order_xml, 'CustomField2', implode( PHP_EOL, $delivery_date_time ) );
```

$shipping_options returns an array for the correct order, however $delivery_date_time contains values from the most recent orders, not the order specified in $order.

I'm sure I've made a simple error in the code and one of you wizards can put me out my misery.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what the output shows? (if you are viewing on a browser, make sure you put the actual source)

Comment: It's difficult, because the output is a character limited text field on another platform. $shipping_options is outputting {"id":183508,"order_id":71471,"name":"\ud83d\udcc6 Delivery Date: Fri, 20 Aug 2021","option_id":"","... as expected, however $delivery_date_time is outputting several 'name' starting with the newest in the database.